# Search through a multi nested list recursively and return a count of integers: Python

Tags: python, recursion

This is a Python program. Here is what I have so far. The program ignores the multi nested lists currently and only counts the single layer values. The method for checking for lists must be indexing.

```
def DigitCount(lst):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return 0
    val = DigitCount(lst[1:])
    if len(lst) > 0:
        if type(lst[0]) != list:
            if type(lst[0]).isdigit():
                return 1 + val
        if type(lst[0])==list:
            DigitCount(lst[0])
            return val
    return val
```

Comment: When you say "count of integers" do you mean the sum or the quantity of elements in the array

Comment: quantity in the array @JGerulskis

Comment: You have a redundant check. you check `if len(lst) == 0:`, then check `if len(lst) > 0:` after it's already guaranteed `len(lst)` is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify you logic using `sum`, recursing over elements that are *lists* calling `DigitCount(ele)` or otherwise checking if the element is an `int` and summing all the results:

```
def DigitCount(lst):
    return sum(DigitCount(ele) if isinstance(ele, list) else isinstance(ele, int) 
               for ele in lst)
```

Output:

```
In [22]: DigitCount([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [3, 4, 3]]]])
Out[22]: 11
```

`isinstance(ele, int)` either returns 0 or 1 so each recursive call either returns 1 or 0 so it is a simple case of summing all the values.